# Implementing interface member from member with a different name

Tags: c#

Say I have the interface:

```cs
interface IThingWithId 
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

...and a class:

```cs
partial class Dog 
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
}
```

**I would like to extend `Dog` such that it implements the interface `IThingWithId`**, but the 'id' for `Dog` has a different name. I had hoped that this would work:

```cs
partial class Dog : IThingWithId {
    public int Id { get; }

    public Dog() {
        Id = DogId;
    }
}
```

But no such luck, I get the error that

> `Dog` does not implement the interface member `IThingWithId.Id`.

Is this possible, or would I need to add a separate member to `Dog` for `Id`?

Comment: How about using adapter pattern?

Comment: You have to know that when you implement an interface, you have to implement all of its method. Here, you implements ID, but you don't keep the same visibility. You should replace int ID by public int ID, then it should work.

Comment: The fact that you need to do this, says you should probably rethink why you need to do this. Why not just have an ID why does it need DogID

Comment: Maybe use explicit interface implementation?

Comment: `public int Id => DogId;` and `public Dog() {}`

Comment: Are you sure that's your actual code? Even with partial class mismatches and whatever, your third sample should work fine.

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm afraid it isn't my code, and I can't adjust the interface

Comment: @Luaan I needed to change the exact naming and structure in order to produce a minimal example, but as far as I can tell it _should_ be the same for all practical purposes

Comment: @DmitryBychenko this seems to me to be the best solution

Comment: The thing is, if I try to compile your sample code, it *does* work. So you must be missing something else in your actual code.

Comment: Glad to see that people managed to gather the general thrust of the question and provide useful answers

Comment: @MickyD there is no 'last example', it's a partial class.

Comment: I'd say the biggest problem is that your sample code doesn't actually produce the order you're giving ;) The only reason I was able to provide a useful answer is that I ignored that, and just provided working sample code that I thought would be useful to solve your problem.

Comment: @Luaan Sure, that makes sense. I could try and see what the exact difference is between what I have in the code base and what is added here, though it'll make little difference now. The standard for questions tagged `c#` seems incredibly high, fair enough really, it's for the community to set it's own standards, it seems a shame to me though that errors in a question which did not prevent users from providing good answers should result in downvoting without suggestions for improvement

Comment: @KekuSemau _"there is no 'last example', it's a partial class"_ -  Ah I C.  Hmmm  pasting all his code together in one file I get no error at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a separate member. However, you can at least use explicit interface implementation to "hide" Id from users of `Dog`:

```
class Dog : IThingWithId
{
  int IThingWithId.Id => DogId;

  public int DogId { get; }
}
```

Now you satisfy the interface:

```
IThingWithId dog = new Dog();
Console.WriteLine(dog.Id);    // works
Console.WriteLine(dog.DogId); // doesn't work, not part of IThingWithId
```

while keeping the public interface of `Dog` simple:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Console.WriteLine(dog.Id);    // doesn't work
Console.WriteLine(dog.DogId); // works
```

Answer (score 3):

On the CLR level, you can have a member of an arbitrary name mapped to a member of implemented interface. But C# doesn't allow that.

Your only option is have a duplicate member, but you can make it "explicit interface implementation", so that it doesn't interfere with the other members, e.g. when you see them listed in the IntelliSense.

```cs
class Dog : IThingWithId 
{
    // the desired members in your class

    public int DogId { get; set; }

    public Dog() 
    {
    }

    // the wrapper member required by the interface

    int IThingWithId.Id => DogId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very much appreciated and useful for me